# Add a currency picklist field in a custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, administration

In a custom object I have to add a picklist of currency, I think something like that exist in Salesforce but I don't know how to find it or enable it in my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you need to contact salesforce support.
Read the following related articles: [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_enable_multicurrency.htm&language=en_US&type=0), [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003638&type=1)